# I Got Error :"the type or namespace name 'namespace2' does not exist int the namespaces 'namespace1' " when i add a WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, web-reference

I have a website with address (non-real) : `www.example.com`.
in this site, i have a service (real) :`http://www.example.com/services/smsService.asmx`.

I have two `asp.net` projects in `visual-studio-2017` :
`project1` and `project2`.
in `project1` when i add a webreference(Add Service Reference... >Advanced...>Add Web Reference...) like `http://www.example.com/services/smsService.asmx` every thing is OK but in `project2` the namespace of webReference doesn't recognize.
in `project1` i use `using NameSpace1.SmsWebService;` and it works, but in `project2` i get that error!
both projects are almost the same

Comment: Is namespace1 and namespace2 in your question is real or you have replaced this with original value for question ?

Comment: thank for your comment @dotnetstep . they are not real. they are base namespaces of that `asp.net WebApplication` projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some `googling` and `stack overflowing` i found that i can add the service in other way.
i used to add the service in this way:
rightClick on Project  > `Add` > `Service Reference...` > `Advanced...` > `Add Web Reference...` and then i write URL and ...
in this way, some files like `*.datasource` couldn't downloaded (i don't know why!) and thus the project failed to build.
I changed my way of add service with this:
rightClick on Project  > `Add` > `Service Reference...` > and then i filled the Address and clicked `GO` Button!
Surprisingly everything was fine! except some classNames need a `SoapClient` at the end. means `oldClass` changed to `oldClassSoapClient` in my code!
At last, this service appeared in `Service References` of solution, not `Web References`
Thank you all buddies

Answer (score 0):

first remove the service refernce that you added before , and rebuild the project then add new service reference
Change the namespace while configuring the web reference reference in project2.
and make sure that the project 1 is not referenced in project2.